# Unsigned int in C behaves negative

Tags: c, printf, undefined-behavior

I don't understand why the output of an unsigned int is negative for the following code.
Just like a signed int.

```
  uint32_t yyy=1<<31;
  printf("%d\n",yyy);
```

The output is:

> -2147483648

which is `-2^31`.

Comment: Try   `printf("%u\n",yyy);`

Comment: Even before you call `printf`, this code has undefined behavior, if `int` has 32 bits in your C implementation. The value of `1<<31` overflows an `int`. You should use `1u<<31`, so that it shifts an `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 6):

The format specifier for `%d` expects an `int`, not an `unsigned int`, so the code has undefined behaviour. From the C99 standard section *7.19.6.1 The fprintf function*:

> If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

Use `%u` for `unsigned int`:

```
uint32_t yyy=1u<<31;
printf("%u\n",yyy);
```

Output:

```
2147483648
```

Comment: For portability concerns, one could use the following to print a uint32_t (which may be bigger than an unsigned): 'printf("%"PRIu32"\n", yyy);'

Answer (score 4):

It's because your printf argument, as %d, is implicitly converting your number to an int.

Use %u instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use `%u` to output unsigned numbers:

```
printf("%u\n", yyy);
```

Answer (score 1):

As many have said, use the `%u` identifier.

The reason for this, is that `printf` has no way of telling what type any of the extra parameters are (they are given as a `va_list`), so you the programmer have to provide that information using the format string. When you then provide `%d`, `printf` will call this:

```
int val;
val = va_arg(va_list, int);
```

and implicitly cast your unsigned int into a signed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `unsigned int` format specifier:

```
printf("%u\n",yyy);
        ^^
```

using the wrong format specifier for `printf` is undefined behavior, which is covered in the C99 draft standard section `7.19.6.1` *The fprintf function*, which also covers `printf` with respect to format specifiers says:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
>   undefined.<sup>248)</sup> If any argument is not the correct type for
>   the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

The [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) page for `printf` has a nice table specifying the format specifiers available.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are printing it as signed. Use `%u` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`printf` takes a variable number of arguments. When you call it the compiler will dutifully put them all on the stack. Because it's C there's no reflection — `printf` can't subsequently infer the types of things it has received. At the bit level you can't prima facie tell a signed integer from an unsigned integer or a float, a suitably small structure, part of a larger struct, etc.

That's why you also have to supply a format string. It tells `printf` what types to read from the stack and in what order. It depends entirely on that format string, having no ability to verify it.

Hence, as per the one-line answers already posted, if you tell it to interpret a field as a signed quantity then it'll be printed as a signed quantity.

Answer (score 0):

Integers are stored in [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) format.  This means there is no way to tell if the number is signed or unsigned just by looking at the value.  You must tell the machine which representation you want it to use and keep track of it yourself.

In your example you tell the machine that `jjj` is unsigned (for type checking) but then ask `printf()` to treat it as signed by using `%d` in the format string (it can't get at the type information).  If you want to print an unsigned int use `%u` instead.