# unsigned integer getting overflowed in c

Tags: c

I wrote simple C program to find the maximum positive number I can reach using unsigned integer as given below. Size of integer on my machine is 4 bytes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main()
{
    unsigned int x = 1;
    int i = 1;

    for(; i <= 31; i++)
    {
        x = x * 2;
    }

    unsigned int y = pow(2, 31);

    printf("%d\n", x);
    printf("%d\n", y);
}
```

both `x`, `y` are getting overflowed and value as `-2147483648`. I thought it should not overflow because on the machines where `sizeof(int) = 4` bytes, `unsigned int` range should be  `pow(2, 32) - 1`. Can any one please let me know why this is getting overflowed?

Comment: You're printing them out as signed integers. Use `%u` instead.

Comment: Using the [wrong format specifier](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16738218/1708801) is undefined behavior.

Comment: UINT_MAX might help you, if this is productive code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use %u for unsigned int:

```
printf("%u\n", x);
printf("%u\n", y);
```

Comment: Excellent. I missed small thing.